# Python Flask POST/GET request

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I need help with user authentication in my website. I am using python flask, sqlite3 and DB Browser for SQLite. I'm having trouble with the login part. Each time I try to login and redirect to an html website it says error 404.

Here is the code for the login page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
    <title>PackageDrop Login</title>
    <link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='login.css') }}" />
    <link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='cssmainpage.css') }}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/login" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    Username:<br>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>
    Password:<br>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </body>
</html>
```

The page that is forwarded to is just simple html, nothing special so I am not uploading it.
If you feel like you need more information to understand, ask and I will post quickly.
Thanks for all the help I get.

EDIT1:
Changed in the login.html the form action from "login.html" to "login" and now it gives a 400 Bad Request error.

EDIT2:
The redirection works. I have changed the code for the login but it makes this error: "ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 7812 and this is thread id 7388". The only thing that I did is just connect to the database like this:
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
This is the new code for the login:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    checkP = conn.execute('select pword from users where uname = request.form[\'username\']')
    arrayCheck = checkP.fetchall()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['password'] != arrayCheck[[0][0]]:
            error = 'Incorrect password'
            return redirect(url_for('login.html'))
        elif len(arrayCheck) == 0:
            error = 'Username or password is incorrect'
            return redirect(url_for('login.html'))
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash('You are logged in')
            return redirect(url_for("userpage"))
    return render_template('login.html')
```

Comment: Look at your logic again. You're comparing the username and password values with themselves.

Comment: @DanielRoseman But I am checking the username and password from the post request and then comparing it with the username and password in the database. Is that not how you do it?

Comment: No you're not. Where do you think you are doing that? You get the username from `request.form`, then compare it directly to `request.form['username']`, ie itself.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok, I understand now. So how can I check if the login credentials are correct with the database?

Answer (score 1):

Http `404` code means `page not found`. When you post your form your redirects is to `userpage.html` but your form action is to `/login` route. Your action should be the target page to redirect after post successfully `action="/userpage"` I assume you have `userpage` view function. Or you can leave action blank just try with redirect function `redirect(url_for('userpage'))`. Note `url_for()` function takes view function name not template name. One last thing I didn't pay attention on your login logic.

Comment: The login is supposed to check if the username and password are located in the database. I understand that I didn't do it right, so my question is how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
username = request.form['uname']
password = request.form['pword']
if request.form['uname'] != username:
    error = 'Incorrect username'
if request.form['pword'] != password:
    error = 'Incorrect password'
```

As Daniel Roseman explained this logic is flawed. What you need to do is compare `password` provided by the user with the password you have stored in your database.

In pseudo code, it would look something like this:

```
username = request.form['uname']
password = request.form['pword']
try:
    db_password = my_db.get('uname')
    if password == db_password:
        session['logged_in'] = True
    else: 
        error = "Password provided does not match Database"
except Exception as exc:
    error = "Could not obtain password from Database : {}".format(exc)
```

This is just minimum, of course you could improve on this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It will probably work but I don't just want to copy it, I want to do it in my way. I will post new code that unfortunately gives me an error.